# Chunking Carbon dates into consecutive blocks

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon, laravel-collection

I have a Laravel collection of Carbon dates:

```
$dates = collect([
  Carbon::parse('2020-09-18'),
  Carbon::parse('2020-09-21'),
  Carbon::parse('2020-09-22'),
  Carbon::parse('2020-10-13'),
  Carbon::parse('2020-10-14'),
  Carbon::parse('2020-10-15'),
  Carbon::parse('2020-11-02'),
  Carbon::parse('2020-11-03'),
  Carbon::parse('2020-11-04'),
  Carbon::parse('2020-11-05')
]);
```

I want to split these into chunks where the dates are consecutive weekdays. I've managed to use chunkWhile to split the collection where the dates are either before or after:

```
$chunks = $dates->chunkWhile(function ($date, $key, $chunk) {
  return $date->diffInDays($chunk->last()) < 2;
});
```

However this breaks when a weekend is in between. In the above example the dates '2020-09-18', '2020-09-21', '2020-09-22' are consecutive weekdays but are Fri, Mon and Tue so are split by my current formula. How can I adjust it to ignore weekends.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Carbon, but the logic would be along the lines of `diffInDays < 2 || (diffInDays == 3 && lastChunk->isFriday())` - that is if you're certain that they come chronologically sorted.

Answer (score 2):

`diffInWeekdays` excludes Saturday and Sunday from counting:

```php
$chunks = $dates->chunkWhile(function ($date, $key, $chunk) {
  return $date->diffInWeekdays($chunk->last()) < 2;
});
```

For other "weekend" definition, or custom diff, use `diffInDaysFiltered`

For holidays or custom weeks open days, those Carbon mixins may help:

https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-day

https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-time

Comment: Pefect solution and a great example of why Carbon is so brilliant. So many times I've been stuck with long functions that can be solved by a one line Carbon function!